# How to get the picture of Facebook User using Koala gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch the picture of a Facebook user's friends using
their facebook ids, but using the following code returns nil instead
of the picture url...

The code I am using is as follows:

```
picture_url = @user.get_picture("1000000111")
```

where @user is the Graph API Object made using Facebook
authentication...

What is missing in this code?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Koala, but if you ask for the user's identifier ( in the form of `graph.facebook.com/odedharth/picture` ) you can get it.

Comment: It works fine when I use it in my browser, the browser redirects me to the image, however, it doesn't work in the HTML code because of redirection... How should I overcome this problem??

Comment: Here's the basic HTML code which is not working...`<html>
<body>
<img src="graph.facebook.com/10000010000001/picture" 

alt="Image not found" />
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It doesn't specify how to use Koala.

Answer (score 16):

To get all facebook friend images in ruby on rails. you can use Koala gem 
https://github.com/arsduo/koala

It has got nice doumentation

To get the facebbok friend you can use

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)
friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
friends.each do |f|
  f[:image]= @graph.get_picture(f["id"])
end
```

But this method will take too much time because you will have to send request for each friend.

To avoid this you can use The REST API which koala supports,

```
@rest = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)
@rest.fql_query(my_fql_query) 
@rest.fql_multiquery(fql_query_hash) # convenience method
```

To Write Fql query you can use the facebook table structure which you can find at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

to get Facebook uid , name and pic you can use this one..

```
@rest.fql_query("select uid, name, pic_square from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())")
```

Answer (score 13):

You can also get all friends with their pictures using `get_connection()` as follows

```
friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends?fields=id,name,picture.type(large)")
```

Answer (score 6):

I got the image working by directly using url specified by Cody in image tag as below

```
img  src="http://graph.facebook.com/10000010000001/picture" />

img  src="http://graph.facebook.com/user_profile_id/picture" />
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  USER_PROFILE_OPTIONS = {
    fields: %w(id first_name last_name hometown email 
               gender birthday picture.width(320))
  }.freeze
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)
  @graph.get_object('me', USER_PROFILE_OPTIONS)
```

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Answer (score 3):

Use the access token you've received from oauth

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(access_token)
profile_path = graph.get_picture(uid)
```

To get the path, then to display it

```
<%= image_tag profile_path %>
```

This works for me, and should for you..