# Facebook current profile picture's id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

Is it possible to get `id` of Facebook `user's current profile pic`??

```
pics = @graph.get_connections(album_id, 'photos', {limit: 5}) #album_id is profile picture album id
```

I don't see any info regarding current profile picture in the above result.

Am using Koala gem.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367454/how-to-get-the-picture-of-facebook-user-using-koala-gem

Comment: I did check that. They are using user id to get profile picture's url. They don't get id of the profile picture.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a User Access Token, why aren't you using `/me/picture`? It's not clear to me why you need the objectId of the profile picture...

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Comment: I knew this option. But, the image isn't that clear. With koala's `get_connections(profile_pic_album_id, 'photos')` there are various image sizes available. Even with `type=large` option for `/me/picture` the image isn't clear.